# what/who.(RecordType.Id vs RecordTypeId) SF Bug

Tags: apex, unit-test, bug

```
Task[] tasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE What.RecordType.Id = :AccountsHelper.getPersonAccountRecordType().Id LIMIT 1];

System.debug('tasks size : ' + tasks.size());

Task[] tasks2 = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE What.RecordTypeId = :AccountsHelper.getPersonAccountRecordType().Id LIMIT 1];

System.debug('tasks2 size : ' + tasks2.size());
```

> DEBUG|tasks size : 1

> DEBUG|tasks2 size : 0

Looks like when using polymorphic fields in unit tests RecordTypeId is not working as expected.

When I used the same query with RecordTypeId outside unit tests in:

- dev console query
- salesforce inspector query
- created selector and invoked in dev console

All works as expected.

I bumped API version to 52 and 53 and still the same behaviour in unit test.

Anybody else experienced the same?

Comment: Does your `AccountsHelper.getPersonAccountRecordType()` method contain any specific code to alter behavior for unit tests? Have you tried to system.debug() the results of calling that method after each use (i.e. are you sure it's returning the same data every time in your test)?

Comment: How are the Tasks in the unit test created? Is this a unit test that uses `SeeAllData`? Without some additional code, it's hard to rule out issues coming from the rest of the code, especially if the query works properly elsewhere.

Comment: It's not using SeeAllData. If I put here test builder next person will ask what that builder does behind the scene. When I put some custom field next person will ask if I have some custom logic behind it :D Case is very simple, I only need somebody to create similar unit test and confirm that they experience the same issue RecordTypeId vs RecordType.Id. All you need is to create Task connected with PersonAccount or just Account.
And run those 2 queries.

Comment: Both queries are used in the same unit test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

This is now logged as W-10188438. At this time, there is no ETA for a resolution. The basic problem, as stated by support, is:

> The named entity usecase is missed for person account in implementation during SOQL query execution. In our internal code base, Person account id is added to the query filter only when queried based on Account and Contact entities.

This means that, for the foreseeable future, developers will need to be aware that this problem exists, and what the solution to the problem is. Fortunately, the workaround is simple and relatively limited in scope.

---

I wrote some unit tests:

```
@isTest public class q359389 {
    static final Boolean IS_PERSON = true, IS_BUSINESS = false;
    static Account createAccountAndTask(Boolean isPerson) {
        RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE IsPersonType=:isPerson AND sObjectType='Account' LIMIT 1];
        Account a = new Account(RecordTypeId=rt.Id);
        a.put(isPerson?Account.LastName:Account.Name,'Test');
        insert a;
        Task t = new Task(WhatId=a.Id, Subject='Test', Status='Not Started',Priority='Normal');
        insert t;
        return a;
    }
    enum FILTER_BY { ACCOUNT, WHAT }
    static void doAssert(Account a, FILTER_BY filter) {
        upsert a Account.Id;
        switch on filter {
            when ACCOUNT {
                System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Task WHERE Account.RecordType.Id = :a.RecordTypeId],'Account.RecordType.Id filter failed');
                System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Task WHERE Account.RecordTypeId = :a.RecordTypeId],'Account.RecordTypeId filter failed');
            }
            when WHAT {
                System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Task WHERE What.RecordType.Id = :a.RecordTypeId],'What.RecordType.Id filter failed');
                System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Task WHERE What.RecordTypeId = :a.RecordTypeId],'What.RecordTypeId filter failed');
            }
        }
    }
    @isTest static void filterPersonWithWhatIdByWhatId() {
        doAssert(createAccountAndTask(IS_PERSON), FILTER_BY.WHAT);
    }
    @isTest static void filterPersonWithWhatIdByAccountId() {
        doAssert(createAccountAndTask(IS_PERSON), FILTER_BY.ACCOUNT);
    }
    @isTest static void filterBusinessWithWhatIdByWhatId() {
        doAssert(createAccountAndTask(IS_BUSINESS), FILTER_BY.WHAT);
    }
    @isTest static void filterBusinessWithWhatIdByAccountId() {
        doAssert(createAccountAndTask(IS_BUSINESS), FILTER_BY.ACCOUNT);
    }
    @isTest static void testPersonFieldsDirect() {
        Account a = createAccountAndTask(IS_PERSON);
        Task t = [SELECT What.RecordTypeId FROM Task];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, t.What.RecordTypeId, 'What.RecordTypeId was null');
    }
    @isTest static void testPersonFieldsIndirect() {
        Account a = createAccountAndTask(IS_PERSON);
        Task t = [SELECT What.RecordType.Id FROM Task];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, t.What.RecordType.Id, 'What.RecordType.Id was null');
    }
    @isTest static void testBusinessFields() {
        Account a = createAccountAndTask(IS_BUSINESS);
        Task t = [SELECT What.RecordType.Id, What.RecordTypeId FROM Task];
        System.assertNotEquals(null, t.What.RecordType.Id, 'What.RecordType.Id was null');
        System.assertNotEquals(null, t.What.RecordTypeId, 'What.RecordTypeId was null');
    }
}
```

And found that this only fails for What.RecordTypeId, and only if the Account is a Person Account. In other words, this is definitely a bug, and should be reported. This test is portable to any org that has Person Accounts enabled and minimal validation/automation/etc. You can even run this in a Scratch Org with the feature enabled.

Edited: Also, selecting What.RecordTypeId or What.RecordType.Id results in a null value, so there's some additional problems with Record Types and Person Accounts. I have updated the tests accordingly.

Comment: Based on your experience, how do you suggest to report that? If that's something you have done, you can report that on your behalf. If you can provide some tips what's the best approach to do that, that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Bithermal You'd need Premier Support to log these kinds of bugs. As a Salesforce MVP, I have this level of support, so it's no big deal. I have to say, though, this will probably be closed as NoFix, but at least it will be documented.

Comment: Thanks, keep us posted :)

Comment: I've also asked some of the Support folks that participate here to get an Investigation opened.

Comment: Can you please log a case with Salesforce support and share the case number here so I can take it forward.

Comment: @Swetha Case #41480817. Thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- No there is no alternation when used in Unit tests.
- Just in case I fired the same method multiple times and it's
  returning the same Id, on each execution.
- I also used hardcoded Id instead of method and reversed query if somebody asks this question :)

```
Task[] tasks2 = [SELECT id from task where what.recordTypeId = '0120Y0000002lFXQAY' limit 1];

System.debug('tasks2 size : ' + tasks2.size());

Task[] tasks = [SELECT id from task where what.recordType.Id = '0120Y0000002lFXQAY' limit 1];

System.debug('tasks size : ' + tasks.size());

17:44:22.487 (13974228708)|USER_DEBUG|[343]|DEBUG|tasks2 size : 0

17:44:22.487 (13995022269)|USER_DEBUG|[345]|DEBUG|tasks size : 1
```

Best if sb can reproduce :)