# Why does this query on ContentDocumentLinks work, when the LinkedEntity doesn't have record types?

Tags: soql, contentdocumentlink

When executing this query I'd expect this query to throw an exception, since the object does not have record types.  but it doesn't. Why doesn't it throw an exception

```
 SELECT Id, 
      (SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId 
      FROM ContentDocumentLinks 
      WHERE 
        LinkedEntity.Type = 'CustomObjNameWithoutRecordTypes' AND 
        LinkedEntity.RecordType.DeveloperName IN ('Hello', 'Goodbye'))
      FROM ContentDocument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polymorphic relationships of this nature, it doesn't matter if the filtered object doesn't have record types. As long as it is possible that record types could exist in the org, then filters of this nature will never fail. However, note that sometimes this can also lead to [bugs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/359389/2984), so always test the query to see if it will be a problem.